# VMware Workstation Player: get host OS to capture certain hotkeys or global hotkeys in general

Tags: windows-7, linux, vmware, hotkeys, vmware-player

I am running VMware Workstation Player 12.5.4 on 4.10.13-1-ARCH (i3wm) and my guest OS is Windows 7.

I want to use <kbd>LWin+1/2/3/...</kbd> to switch to workspaces in the host OS (Linux, i3wm) while I'm inside the guest OS (Windows 7) and I don't care that it overlaps with the default Windows functionality of focusing the n-th window in the taskbar.

Alternatively, allowing all global hotkeys of the host OS to be used from within the guest OS would also solve my problem, but it could get in the way (<kbd>LWin+e</kbd> changes container layout, for instance). I haven't been able to find this kind of setting because the configuration menu of VMware Workstation *Player* is really limited and there isn't a definitive guide for configuring `/etc/vmware/config` that I know of.

---

If this can't be solved, I'll post my current makeshift solution implemented in AutoHotkey (guest) and Python (host). It isn't perfect, because keeping <kbd>LWin</kbd> pressed after exiting guest OS prevents new hotkeys requiring <kbd>LWin</kbd> from being used (probably because the host never got the keydown?). It also only works on i3wm (host), but the idea could probably be reused for other configurations.